# problem with intl and zip package of php for magento

Tags: php, magento, zip, magento2, intl

[image]

I try to install Magento 2 but when i do composer update tell me there is an error and the intl and zip package there isn't in the system.

I try to install this package but the error persist, i try to reinstall with brew but continue to give me an error, i try to add the package on the php.ini but nothing.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can install php extensions using pecl. For ex

```
pecl install intl
```

If you need to check which php version you are using; Run bellow command

```
which php
```

You can check whether the intl extension is installed properly using bellow commands

```
php -m | grep intl
#or you can use
pecl search intl
```